# Function definition using type synonym is "less polymorphic than expected"

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism, ghci

Given this type synonym:

```
type Synonym a b = (a, b)
```

this code doesn't work in GHCi:

```
ghci> let myFirst (f, s) = f :: Synonym a b -> a

<interactive>:1:21:
    Inferred type is less polymorphic than expected
      Quantified type variable `b' is mentioned in the environment:
        f :: Synonym a b -> a (bound at <interactive>:1:13)
      Quantified type variable `a' is mentioned in the environment:
        f :: Synonym a b -> a (bound at <interactive>:1:13)
    In the expression: f :: Synonym a b -> a
    In the definition of `myFirst':
        myFirst (f, s) = f :: Synonym a b -> a
```

but this does:

```
ghci> let myFirst = fst :: Synonym a b -> a
-- no problem --
```

This only happens when I type it directly into GHCi; both definitions work when I put them in files and `:load` them.

What is the problem here?  I've run into this issue many times, but never understood why.

p.s. I tried `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction`, but that didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Haskell is trying to match the type signature to `f`, not to `myFirst`, and it doesn't work (I can't give more explanation than that though, someone else?). i.e. Haskell is treating it as:

```
let myFirst (f,s) = (f :: Synonym a b -> a)
```

You can fix this giving a separate signature

```
let myFirst :: Synonym a b -> a; myFirst (f,s) = f
```

or even using a lambda (this is essentially equivalent to the `myFirst = fst` definition)

```
let myFirst = (\(f,s) -> f) :: Synonym a b -> a
```

(Note that this fails even without the type synonym: `let myFirst (f,s) = f :: (a,b) -> a` doesn't work either.)